# Referencing button clicks to retrieve appropriate values from array

Tags: jquery

I'm building a list of links dynamically using an array, which will result in something like this:

```
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
   <p class="link">label</p>
</div>
```

Then I would have a click handler:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
//do something
 myarray[?].stuff;
});
```

I want to retrieve something from an array, but I'm not sure what the best way is to reference the link. I could add the array key as an id in the p tag, however I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of handling it.

Comment: I don't think I understand fully.. When you say you want retrieve something from an array, do you mean that you want to retrieve a `value` from an `array` based on its `key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the index, but that will give you :

```
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p> //0
   <p class="link">label</p> //1
</div>
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p> //0
   <p class="link">label</p> //1
</div>

//js
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    myarray[$(this).index()].stuff;
});
```

You could use the parents index aswell, something like :

```
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p> //0
   <p class="link">label</p> //1
</div>
<div>
   <p class="link">label</p> //10
   <p class="link">label</p> //11
</div>

//js
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    var numb = parseFloat($(this).parent().index().toString() + $(this).index().toString());
    myarray[numb]);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Wxu5M/)

or a data attribute

```
<div>
   <p class="link" data-i="0">label</p>
   <p class="link" data-i="1">label</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p class="link" data-i="2">label</p>
   <p class="link" data-i="3">label</p>
</div>

//js
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    myarray[$(this).data('i')].stuff;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with using the `key` as an identifier (it isn't really relevant which attribute you assign that to, though generally I tend to use `id`). This way your `<p>`'s `id` (or whichever attribute you assign it to) will always match up with the corresponding array property.

From past experience, it's generally a good idea to append/prepend something to the attribute (particularly if it's the `id`, to prevent duplicating element `id`'s, then use the `.replace()` method to strip out everything except what you need)